# How to programmatically organize and group albums in the default gallery app?

Tags: samsung, file-management, automation, gallery

As the title  says, i'm wondering if it's possible to organize and group my albums on the default galley app that comes with android on samsung galaxy tablets? And by that i mean is there some sort of xml file or the like i can modify that will tell the app to group certain albums?

Thank you